# Does innodb_buffer_pool_size accept "*GB" values?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I thinks `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is specified in bytes, would typing in values with unit (i.e 1024MB or 1GB) work? Has anyone already tried this?

**Specs:**

- MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GB or MB wont work. However, any variable that you needs to be defined as a numeric value can use the shorthand byte suffixes K, M or G.

From the docs:

> For variables that take a numeric value, the value can be given with a
>   suffix of K, M, or G (either uppercase or lowercase) to indicate a
>   multiplier of 1024, 1024^2 or 1024^3. (For example, when used to set
>   max_allowed_packet, the suffixes indicate units of kilobytes,
>   megabytes, or gigabytes.)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/program-variables.html

So, if you wanted 1024MB then you would use 1024M or 1G